# Opening nested dict in a single column to multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data in nested dicts form from json:-

```
{
    "simple25b" : {
        "hands" : {
            "0" : {
                "handId" : "xyz",
                "time" : "2019-09-23 11:00:01",
                "currency" : "rm"
            },
            "1" : {
                "handId" : "abc",
                "time" : "2019-09-23 11:01:18",
                "currency" : "rm"
            }
        }
    },
    "simple5af" : {
        "hands" : {
            "0" : {
                "handId" : "akg",
                "time" : "2019-09-23 10:53:22",
                "currency" : "rm"
            },
            "1" : {
                "handId" : "mzc",
                "time" : "2019-09-23 10:54:15",
                "currency" : "rm"
            },
            "2" : {
                "handId" : "swk",
                "time" : "2019-09-23 10:56:03",
                "currency" : "rm"
            },
            "3" : {
                "handId" : "pQc",
                "time" : "2019-09-23 10:57:15",
                "currency" : "rm"
            },
            "4" : {
                "handId" : "ywh",
                "time" : "2019-09-23 10:58:53",
                "currency" : "rm"
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to change this into a single dataframe object so that it results in something like this:-
[image: Output]

I have tried loop, changing the column to list after reading it as json:-

```
#reading data
with open("data.json", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as datafile:
    data = json.load(datafile)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.transpose()
```

I have also tried this:-

```
pd.concat([df1.drop(['hands'], axis=1), df1['hands'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

but nothing gives.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({(i,k):data[i][j][k] for i in data for j in data[i] for k in data[i][j]}).T.reset_index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is add `PIDS` and `Hands` keys to last dictionaries and append to `list of dict` - so last `DataFrame` constructor working nice:

```
L = []
for k, v in data.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            v2['PIDS'] = k
            v2['Hands'] = k2
            L.append(v2)

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)

  handId                 time currency       PIDS Hands
0    xyz  2019-09-23 11:00:01       rm  simple25b     0
1    abc  2019-09-23 11:01:18       rm  simple25b     1
2    akg  2019-09-23 10:53:22       rm  simple5af     0
3    mzc  2019-09-23 10:54:15       rm  simple5af     1
4    swk  2019-09-23 10:56:03       rm  simple5af     2
5    pQc  2019-09-23 10:57:15       rm  simple5af     3
6    ywh  2019-09-23 10:58:53       rm  simple5af     4
```

With changed ordering loops solution:

```
L = []
for k, v in data.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            a = {'PIDS':k, 'Hands': k2}
            L.append({**a, **v2})
```

And list comprehension alternative:

```
L = [{**{'PIDS':k, 'Hands': k2}, **v2} 
         for k, v in data.items() 
         for k1, v1 in v.items() 
         for k2, v2 in v1.items()]


df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
        PIDS Hands handId                 time currency
0  simple25b     0    xyz  2019-09-23 11:00:01       rm
1  simple25b     1    abc  2019-09-23 11:01:18       rm
2  simple5af     0    akg  2019-09-23 10:53:22       rm
3  simple5af     1    mzc  2019-09-23 10:54:15       rm
4  simple5af     2    swk  2019-09-23 10:56:03       rm
5  simple5af     3    pQc  2019-09-23 10:57:15       rm
6  simple5af     4    ywh  2019-09-23 10:58:53       rm
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use recurssion to do this like below to work on any depth

```py
def convert_to_df(d, col_names, depth=0):
    df_list = []
    for key, value in d.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            df = convert_to_df(value, col_names, depth+1)
            df.loc[:,col_names[depth]] = key
            df_list.append(df)
        else:
            return pd.DataFrame([d.values()], columns=d.keys())
    return pd.concat(df_list)


col_names_for_depth = ["PID","", "Hands"]
df = convert_to_df(d, col_names_for_depth)

## rearrange columns and remove colums for depth of "hands"
new_cols = list(df.columns[[-1, -3]]) + list(df.columns[:-3])
df.reindex(new_cols, axis=1)
```